# DirectX11 Desktop duplication not working with NVIDIA

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm trying too use [DirectX desktop duplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx).

I tried running exmaples from

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116253/Desktop-Screen-Capture-on-Windows-via-Windows-Desk

And from

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a

Both of these are examples of screen capture using DXGI.

I have `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060` with `Windows 10 Pro` on the machine. It has `Intel™ Core i7-6700HQ` processor.

These examples work perfectly fine when `NVIDIA Control Panel > 3D Settings` is selected to `Auto select processor`.

However if I set the setting manually to `NVIDIA Graphics Card` the samples stop working.

Error occurs at the following line.

```
//IDXGIOutput1* DxgiOutput1
hr = DxgiOutput1->DuplicateOutput(m_Device, &m_DeskDupl);
```

**Error in `hr(HRESULT)` is `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED 0x887A0004`**

I'm new to DirectX and I don't know the issue here, **is DirectX desktop duplication not supported on NVIDIA** ?

If that's the case then is there a way to select a particular processor at the start of program so that program can run with any settings ?

**#Edit**

After looking around I asked the developer (Evgeny Pereguda) of the second sample project on [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116253/Desktop-Screen-Capture-on-Windows-via-Windows-Desk)

Here's a link to the discussion
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116253/Desktop-Screen-Capture-on-Windows-via-Windows-Desk?msg=5319978#xx5319978xx

Posting the screenshot of the discussion on codeproject.com in case original link goes down

[image: discussion with Evgeny Pereguda]

I also found an [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349427/desktop-duplication-api-switchable-graphics) which unequivocally suggested that it could not be done with the desktop duplication API referring to support ticket at microsoft's support site https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3019314/error-generated-when-desktop-duplication-api-capable-application-is-ru

Quote from the ticket

> This issue occurs because the DDA does not support being run against
>   the discrete GPU on a Microsoft Hybrid system. By design, the call
>   fails together with error code DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED in such a
>   scenario.

However there are some applications which are efficiently duplicating desktop on windows in both modes (integrated graphics and discrete) on my machine. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjE6qXd6Itw)

I have looked into the installation folder of the `Virtual Desktop` on my machine and can see following `DLLs` of interest

```
SharpDX.D3DCompiler.dll
SharpDX.Direct2D1.dll
SharpDX.Direct3D10.dll
SharpDX.Direct3D11.dll
SharpDX.Direct3D9.dll
SharpDX.dll
SharpDX.DXGI.dll
SharpDX.Mathematics.dll
```

Its probably an indication that this application is using DXGI to duplicate desktop, or may be the application is capable of selecting a specific processor before it starts.

Anyway the question remains, is there any other efficient method of duplicating desktop in both modes?

Comment: Ever have any luck with finding out how an application like Virtual Desktop seems to be side stepping this limitation? We've been banging our head against this issue for a couple of weeks and still haven't found a performant alternative that works with hybrid setups and runs on the dedicated GPU.

Comment: Apologies, but I dropped the project as I was not able to solve it. I added all the information that I collected in this question to help others in future to dig deeper.

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause is certain internal limitation for Desktop Duplication API, described in [Error generated when Desktop Duplication API-capable application is run against discrete GPU](https://support.microsoft.com/help/3019314):

> ... when the application tries to duplicate the desktop image against the discrete GPU on a Microsoft Hybrid system, the application may not run correctly, or it may generate one of the following errors:
>
> - Failed to create windows swapchain with 0x80070005
> - CDesktopCaptureDWM: IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput failed: 0x887a0004

The article does not suggest any other workaround except use of a different GPU (without more specific detail as for whether it is at all achievable programmatically):

> To work around this issue, run the application on the integrated GPU instead of on the discrete GPU on a Microsoft Hybrid system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had abandoned that project, however a discussion on this topic may help someone else. From what I can recall I was trying to run Unity's (game engine) native programming capability to get desktop screenshots in 3D space to finally make it visible in a VR application. I had turned on discrete graphics probably because Unity functioned better with GPU and I was getting BSOD in integrated mode so my manufacturer recommended the same. I also found some other stuff which I post in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft introduced a registry value that can be set programmatically to control which GPU an application runs on. Full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801374/10240943).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to validate if this works.