# Can I specify GPU for Windows 10 application via manifest?

Tags: windows-10, gpu, direct2d

I have a Windows desktop app using Direct2D. On systems with both integrated and discrete GPUs it's possible for the user to configure the app to use the more powerful discrete GPU via Display Settings, as described here. https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-110

Is there a way of adjusting this setting programmatically, so that the application is automatically configured to use the "high performance" GPU without user fettling? Possibly thought a manifest or version resource?

Comment: It's possible to explicitly specific DXGI device when creating D2D device. To pick high performance adapter you could use IDXGIFactory6::EnumAdapterByGpuPreference(), if it's not too new for your needs. I don't recall this to be configurable through manifests. And this question is not really related specifically to D2D.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically set Graphics Performance for an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732181/programmatically-set-graphics-performance-for-an-app)