# How to programmatically select dedicated Intel GPU?

Tags: 3d, gpu, directx, intel, dxgi

Related to [Forcing Machine to Use Dedicated Graphics Card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823372/forcing-machine-to-use-dedicated-graphics-card)

I want to use dedicated GPU (Intel Arc in my case) for the app.

For AMD / Nvidia we can select related dedicated GPUs by exporting special variables to be read by graphics runtime:

```
extern "C" {

// Starting with the Release 302 drivers, application developers can direct the
// Nvidia Optimus driver at runtime to use the High Performance Graphics to
// render any application - even those applications for which there is no
// existing application profile.
//
// See
// https://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf
__declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;

// This will select the high performance AMD GPU as long as no profile exists
// that assigns the application to another GPU.  Please make sure to use a 13.35
// or newer driver.  Older drivers do not support this.
//
// See
// https://community.amd.com/t5/firepro-development/can-an-opengl-app-default-to-the-discrete-gpu-on-an-enduro/td-p/279440
__declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;

}  // extern "C"
```

Do we have some way to ensure app without Intel graphics profile will start on dedicated Intel GPU?

It's possible to manually enumerate installed GPUs using `IDXGIFactory6::EnumAdapterByGpuPreference` with `DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE` flag and choose dedicated GPU(s) if present.

But if simpler way is possible, it will be handy.

Comment: You can't choose the GPU but you can request Windows to use the hi-performance one  as explained here: [Programmatically set Graphics Performance for an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732181/programmatically-set-graphics-performance-for-an-app) which is equivalent to enum and use adapters by hi-performance  preference

Comment: @SimonMourier Well, it is internal implementations details of Win32 API, so a bit risky to use reliably :)

Anyway, much better than nothing. Add this trick when use Vulkan renderer (without DXGI), thank you!